# Как переместить элемент html вниз/вверх?

Tags: html, css

нужно расположить 9 картинок квадратом (как кубик рубика). Результат кода на картинке. Все перепробовал, но получается какой-то бред.[image: s]

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Дизайнерське меню</title>
  <style>
  .first {
   display : block;
   margin : 3 auto;
   margin-right: 54.5%;
  }
  .second {
   display : block;
   margin : 3 auto;
  }
  .third {
   display : block;
   margin : 3 auto;
   margin-left: 54.5%;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body bgcolor="#2c2c2c">
  <img src="images/1.png" class="first" top: 500;>
  <img src="images/2.png" class="first">
  <img src="images/3.png" class="first">
  <img src="images/4.png" class="second">
  <img src="images/5.png" class="second">
  <img src="images/6.png" class="second">
  <img src="images/7.png" class="third">
  <img src="images/8.png" class="third">
  <img src="images/9.png" class="third">
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменил ваш код, теперь он работает как надо.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Дизайнерське меню</title>
      <style>
         body {
           background-color: #2c2c2c;
         }
         .wrapper {
           display: flex;
           flex-wrap: wrap;
           justify-content: space-between;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <img src="images/1.png">
         <img src="images/2.png">
         <img src="images/3.png" >
         <img src="images/4.png">
         <img src="images/5.png">
         <img src="images/6.png">
         <img src="images/7.png">
         <img src="images/8.png" >
         <img src="images/9.png">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай через grid так удобней

```
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2vw; /* это своего рода margin */
}
```